# subscribe sensor_message/Image without opencv

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to print(or just read) the content(i.e. the 'data' field) of a ROS topic of type "sensor_message/Image", but without OpenCV(for performance consideration). Here is a snippet of some naive codes that I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
PKG = 'numpy_tutorial'
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest(PKG)
import rospy 
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image 

def callback(Image):
    print (Image.data)

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener')
    rospy.Subscriber('/camera/color/image_raw', Image, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

But it just prints some unreadable characters in console, I anticipated that it's not just 'print(Image.data)', but how can I do it correctly in python? besides, my ultimate goal is to transform 'data' to numpy array format.

Many thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332070/subscribe-sensor_message/image-without-opencv/) by [GXY](https://answers.ros.org/users/36948/gxy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](https://answers.ros.org/question/64318/how-do-i-convert-an-ros-image-into-a-numpy-array/) question contains answers that might solve your problem.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GXY](https://answers.ros.org/users/36948/gxy/) on 2019-09-07**:
thanks, it worked

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-09-08**:
I am glad it helped, you can accept the answer as correct in that case

**Comment by [GXY](https://answers.ros.org/users/36948/gxy/) on 2019-09-10**:
Sorry, may I also ask how to accept an answer here?

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-09-11**:
You can mark the answer as correct by clicking the tick mark just left of the answer